# Invite External Users gives ULS error

Tags: office-365

We're running an Office 365 SharePoint Online Extranet Solution. When I invite external users and add information text, I get an ULS error and the all but informative error:

## Sorry, something went wrong

Invalid text value.
A text field contains invalid data. Pleas check the value and try again.

If I don't add text, it works perfectly. What may cause this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Talking to Microsoft Office Support in Ireland, they say it's a limit of 255 characters including blanks. They tested the issue and found that 255 characters where maximum and that 256 characters would give the error described above.

I tried it myself and got the error on 256 characters:

> "Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one o"

But got no error on 255 characters:

> "Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one "

Test text from http://lipsum.com/

Answer (score 4):

There appears to be a 256 char limit in the personal message that accompanies the invite - is it possible you are going over this limit?
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2880758

Answer (score 0):

Following article is archived http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2880758 .
Let us know if there is any latest one.

Product team please release official article for this issue

Issue description:- Share invitation email where it won't allow more than 256 characters"

Error message Sorry:- something went wrong Invalid text value. A text field contains invalid data. Please check the value and try again.

Comment: I think this is posted in the wrong system. StackExchange is not a part of Microsoft.